# How to remove a word if it contains a number in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to figure out how to remove a word if it contains numbers. For example I have the sentence "Lorum ipsum: 7-Dt Dolor Sit, Amet 8-AM. Consectetur adipiscing". What I want to remove is "7-Dt" and "8-AM"

I have tried:

```
$str = 'Lorum ipsum: 7-Dt Dolor Sit, Amet 8-AM. Consectetur adipiscing';
$arr = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\']/"," ",$str);                                                                   
echo($arr);
// Outputs: Lorum ipsum Dt Dolor Sit Amet AM Consectetur adipiscing
```

With my solution it only removes the numbers but not the letters/words behind it.

Preferably I create a function so I can use it multiple times.

Comment: Try `preg_replace("/\S*?\d\S*/", " ",$str)`, but do you also want to remove just numbers? What about punctuation?

Comment: That did it. Although, it removes the dot after 8-AM.
Could you please explain me why this does work?

Comment: @Mark Uncapitalize `\S` to `\s` and it'll work perfectly

Comment: The `\S` matches any char but whitespace, if you need the dot, try `preg_replace("/(?:[^\s\d]+\d|\d+[^\s\d])\S*\b(?!\w)/", " ",$str)`. All depends on what you consider a "word"

Comment: I didn't know about the `\S` feature, I guess I learned something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove *words consisting of letters, digits or underscores*, and containing a digit you may use

```
preg_replace("/[^\W\d]*\d\w*/", " ",$str)
```

To remove *chunks of non-whitespace characters* that contain a digit, use

```
preg_replace("/[^\s\d]*\d\S*/", " ",$str)
```

If a digit should be mixed with other chars you need to remove, use

```
preg_replace("/(?:[^\W\d]+\d|\d+[^\W\d])\w*/", " ",$str) 
preg_replace("/(?:[^\s\d]+\d|\d+[^\s\d])\S*/", " ",$str)
```

**In your concrete case**, since you also want to keep the trailing punctuation, you may use

```
preg_replace("/(?:[^\s\d]+\d|\d+[^\s\d])\S*\b/", " ",$str)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/NrdLV), the `\b` word boundary will require the last char matches with `\S*` to be a word char. In some cases, you would even need to make sure there is no word char after it, then you will replace `\b` with `\b(?!\w)`.

**Pattern details**

- `[^\s\d]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and digits
- `\d` - a digit
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars
- `[^\W\d]*\d\w*` - matches 0 or more chars other than non-word and digit chars, then a digit, and then 0+ word chars ("word" char is a letter, digit or `_`)
- `(?:[^\s\d]+\d|\d+[^\s\d])` - matches either of the two alternatives:

  - `[^\s\d]+\d` - 1+ chars other than a whitespace and digit and then a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+[^\s\d]` - 1+ digits and then a char other than a whitespace and digit

Comment: Perfect and well explained. In your demo though it adds extra white space after "Amet" is that removable as well?

Comment: @Mark It does add spaces because you have it in the replacement pattern. Replace with an empty string if you do not want that. Use `preg_replace("/\s*(?:[^\s\d]+\d|\d+[^\s\d])\S*\b/", "", $str)` if you just want to remove the matches.